# Where does AWS codeBuild Local cache is stored and how is it managed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, gradle, aws-codebuild

Where does AWS codeBuild Local cache is stored and how is it managed?
I'm testing AWS Code build, I tried to store maven and gradle dependencies in S3 and it works fine but, it still takes some time to download cache from s3.
Now I'm exploring local type cache, I don't quite understand how it works,
AWS says that Local caching stores a cache on a build host. but for how long it is available for builds? and is it good idea to use for caching maven dependencies?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where does AWS codeBuild Local cache is stored and how is it managed?

They don't publicly tell how it's managed.

Under the hood, it creates symlinks to the cached folders in your build directory, so the only realistic way it can happen that it lives on an EBS volume attached to the agent workload, which does not die immediately once the agent stops.

> but for how long it is available for builds?

They don't publicly disclose it, but from my observations it's minutes (10-15).

> and is it good idea to use for caching maven dependencies?

It's mostly useful for caching docker layers (because they don't lend themselves easily to be stored on S3).

The official recommendation is to use S3 for "infrequent builds".

I gather it means that if you have enough build activity to keep your cache alive, you would be better off using it either way, because they don't seem to charge for it explicitly (unlike S3 transfers).